# Sorting complete node based on grand-child (with qualifier)

Tags: xslt, mapping, xslt-1.0

I need to sort a node by the value of a grand-grand-child. For this I found different examples, but the child G_SG16 appears several times and I need to add a qualifier (here DOC). It could also be that the qualifier DOC does not exits.

Here the line item node G_SG15 that should be sorted including all sub notes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:DESADV96A xmlns:ns0="urn:DESADV">
    <DifferentNodes/>
    <G_SG10>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>10</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>DOC</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>333</D_1154>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>20</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>DOC</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>111</D_1154>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>30</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>DOC</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>222</D_1154>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>40</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
    </G_SG10>
</ns0:DESADV96A>
```

Result should look like this. It is not important if the node without DOC appears at begining or end of the sorted list.

```
result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:DESADV96A xmlns:ns0="urn:DESADV">
    <DifferentNodes/>
    <G_SG10>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>20</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>DOC</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>111</D_1154>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>30</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>DOC</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>222</D_1154>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>10</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>DOC</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>333</D_1154>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
        <G_SG15>
            <S_LIN>
                <D_1082>40</D_1082>
            </S_LIN>
            <G_SG16>
                <S_RFF>
                    <C_C506>
                        <D_1153>WE</D_1153>
                        <D_1154>Customer</D_1154>
                        <D_1156/>
                        <D_4000/>
                    </C_C506>
                </S_RFF>
            </G_SG16>
        </G_SG15>
    </G_SG10>
</ns0:DESADV96A>
```

I tested this one, but it just gives back the source text as it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="G_SG15">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:sort select="/G_SG16/S_RFF/C_C506/D_1154" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course the qualifier is still missing, but I hoped that he starts sorting somehow.

I am using an online editor for this. Does anyone know a good (free) debugger for XSLT? Especially why my rule is not used I could not see with a simple editor.

Thanks for your support :-)
Chris

Comment: Almost done with this mapping on my own. This change in XSL almost works fine:
`
....
  <xsl:template match="G_SG10">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SG15">
        <xsl:sort select="G_SG16/S_RFF/C_C506[D_1153='CN']/D_1154" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
....
`
But he doesn't copy other subnodes from G_SG10. How to tell him just to copy other nodes and only sort G_SG15 ?
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

took me a little while, but I figure out with try and error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="G_SG10">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(contains(name(), 'G_SG15'))]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SG15">
                <xsl:sort select="G_SG16/S_RFF/C_C506[D_1153='DOC']/D_1154" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My first fault was not to select G_SG10 but G_SG15 to sort the G_SG15 which did not worked. Also adding all subnodes next to G_SG15 with [not(contains(name(), 'G_SG15'))] was a little bit try and error. Main problem is if you don't have XMLSpy or something like this to debug a XSL.

Regards
Chris